# View does not exist in Python 3, but does in Python 2

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have the following code in my views.py:

```
def view1(request):
  # do view1-y things
  return view_common(request, mode=True)

def view2(request):
  # do view2-y things
  return view_common(request, mode=False)

# not registered in urls.py
def view_common(request, mode):
   return render(...)
```

This doesn't work under Python 3, resulting in "view does not exist" error. How can I solve that?

Comment: Please post the traceback.

Comment: did you try moving `view_common` above `view1` ?

Comment: @karthikr: that helped, thanks. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  The code posted run fine in 3.5.  The error message  is not one that could have come from Python for this code.  There is no name `view` in the code.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the way Python is interpreting your views.

When the view method `view1` is executed, `view_common` is still not in context. Hence the issue. Move the helper method *before* the view so that it is in context. This would address the issue.

Here is a demo:

Lets say there is a python file, `test.py`:

```
x = add_three(2, 3, 4)
print (x)

def add_three(x, y, z):
    return plus(plus(x, y), z)

def plus(x, y):
    return x + y
```

The output:

```
$:~$ python3 test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 1, in <module>
    x = add_three(2, 3, 4)
NameError: name 'add_three' is not defined
```

But if the methods are rearranged to:

```
def add_three(x, y, z):
    return plus(plus(x, y), z)

def plus(x, y):
    return x + y

x = add_three(2, 3, 4)
print (x)
```

The output is as expected. Note that, `plus` is already in context when it is called from `add_three`. Hence it does not fail.

Comment: A method is a function that is an attribute of a class.  `view1`, etc, are functions but not methods.  The posted code never calls any function and it runs fine in 3.x, so there is no demonstrated error to explain.  The fact that a function must exist or be defined before being called did not change between 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: 'When the view method view1 is executed, view_common is still not in context.' makes no sense unless the view is executed in the module level before the `def view_common()`. Also, the `x = add_three(...)` will fail with the same reason but it is not because of the undefined of `plus`.

Comment: Do you have any insight into why it would work in Python 2 and not 3? I assume it's some kind of Django weirdness, but would be good info.